# How to test flutter url_launcher that email app opens?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I do have a Snackbar with a SnackbarAction which should open the default email app with a default subject and body on tap. I am wondering if there is somehow the possibility to verify if this really happens with some unit tests.

My Snackbar code looks like this:

```
SnackBar get snackbar =>
      SnackBar(
          content: Text(message),
          action: SnackBarAction(
              key: const Key('ErrorSnackbarAction'),
              label: AppLocalizations
                  .of(_context)
                  .report,
              onPressed: () async => await launch('mailto:test@test.com?subject=TestSubject&body=TestBody')));
```

I am already verifying the appearance which works fine:

```
group('ErrorSnackbar', () {
  testWidgets('appearance test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(_generateSnackbarApp());

    await _showSnackbar(tester);

    expect(find.text(userMessage), findsOneWidget);
    expect(find.byWidgetPredicate((Widget widget) =>
    widget is SnackBarAction && widget.label == 'Report'), findsOneWidget);
  });

  testWidgets('error report test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(_generateSnackbarApp());

    await _showSnackbar(tester);

    tester.tap(find.byKey(errorSnackbarAction));
    await tester.pump();

   // how to verify that the default email app was opened
  // with expected subject and body?

  });
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: You can't.

The launch with `mailto` is handled by the OS of the device and is out of context of the flutter app. 
As the flutter test package focuses on the flutter app, what happens on the OS is out of reach.

Answer (score 2):

You can ensure that `launchUrl` is called and the expected parameters were passed. The `url_launcher` package should be tested. Therefore, we can expect that the email app opens, when we call `launchUrl` with the `mailto:` schema.

Here is a short introduction on how to test the `url_launcher` package:

Add `plugin_platform_interface` and `url_launcher_platform_interface` to your dev dependencies:

```yaml
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  plugin_platform_interface: any
  url_launcher_platform_interface: any
```

Copy the `mock_url_launcher_platform.dart` from the `url_launcher` package: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/main/packages/url_launcher/url_launcher/test/mocks/mock_url_launcher_platform.dart

Now you can test the `launchUrl` calls like this:

```dart
void main() {
  late MockUrlLauncher mock;

  setUp(() {
    mock = MockUrlLauncher();
    UrlLauncherPlatform.instance = mock;
  });

  group('$Link', () {
    testWidgets('calls url_launcher for external URLs with blank target',
        (WidgetTester tester) async {
      FollowLink? followLink;

      await tester.pumpWidget(Link(
        uri: Uri.parse('http://example.com/foobar'),
        target: LinkTarget.blank,
        builder: (BuildContext context, FollowLink? followLink2) {
          followLink = followLink2;
          return Container();
        },
      ));

      mock
        ..setLaunchExpectations(
          url: 'http://example.com/foobar',
          useSafariVC: false,
          useWebView: false,
          universalLinksOnly: false,
          enableJavaScript: true,
          enableDomStorage: true,
          headers: <String, String>{},
          webOnlyWindowName: null,
        )
        ..setResponse(true);
      await followLink!();
      expect(mock.canLaunchCalled, isTrue);
      expect(mock.launchCalled, isTrue);
    });
  });
}
```

Copied the test from https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/main/packages/url_launcher/url_launcher/test/link_test.dart

Answer (score 2):

**Unit test wise**

I think the best way to test it is to wrap url launcher with your own class.
This way you can mock it and check that your logic calls your wrapper class function to launch the mail app. This should be enough.

As for the actual mail app or browser (in my case) you should trust the library todo what it supposed to so no need to unit test it really.